# OpenShift › graylog and openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, graylog2, graylog

somebody put graylog in openshift? 
I have tried to take advantage of three ways, but they all receive different errors.

1. http://docs.graylog.org/en/latest/pages/installation/docker.html

   /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 34: exec: graylog: not found
2. https://www.graylog.org/blog/28-centralized-docker-container-logging-with-native-graylog-integration

   [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/container_environment'
3. github.com/swcc/docker-graylog2

   /opt/graylog2/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /etc/graylog2 (Errno::EACCES)

Comment: You might want to ask this question on the public mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/graylog2

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/graylog2/ffKvQQDvpc4 + https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openshift/bjp3BpUVGB8

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix - Set a service account for graylog and give it the `anyuid` scc.

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z useroot
```

Harder (but safer) fix? Build your own Dockerfile for graylog and set up permissions/users properly so it doesn't have to run as root.